# Edit ASCII value in Assembler (using Immunity Debugger)

Tags: disassembly, immunity-debugger

I am trying to edit ASCII String via Immunity Debugger:

[image: Text]

However when I right click to do binary edit and then I click ok, the MOV DWORD instruction is replaced with some random instruction which cause the program to crash:

[image: Text]

This is the result:

[image: Text]

Why is the MOV DWORD instruction completely destroyed and replaced with these random instructions ?

Comment: the string is only referenced in the mov opcode. you need to edit it not here but where it is defined.

Comment: Looks like your string is saved at 0x40723A. Instead of changing the instruction change bytes at 0x40723A.